Using interface in angular 15 forces us to remove operational chain and throws error in template, Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
I shared the interface, ts and html file.

Error:: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
88 <thead *ngIf="invData?.columns && invData?.columns?.[table] && (invData?.columns?.[table]).length > 0">

Component.html::
<div *ngFor="let table of invData?.tables;trackBy: utilServ.trackByFnIndex">
    <table>                                                     
        <thead *ngIf="invData?.columns && invData.columns?.[table] && (invData?.columns?.[table]).length > 0"></thead>
    </table>
</div>

Component.ts::
 interface Column {name: string;type: string;id?: number | string;}
 interface ColumnObj {[key: string]: Column[];}
 interface InvData {columns?: ColumnObj; tables: string[]}
 invData: InvData;

Interface forces me to remove operational chain, but invData.columns can be undefined. We can't remove operational because it can be undefined at run time.
If I remove operational chain then it shows me error on (invData?.columns?.[table]).length that the object may be undefined.
How can I check *ngIf condition on thead mentioned above.

interface InvData {columns?: ColumnObj; tables: string[] | undefined}

Per my understanding, it's only necessary to do the safe check ?. once for the chain, so you can simplify the code.
The error was caused due to undefined being compared to number, we can use the JavaScript || or operator to solve this issue:
<div *ngFor="let table of invData.tables;trackBy: utilServ.trackByFnIndex"> <!-- removed ?. because tables will not be undefined as per the interface! -->
    <table>                     
        <!-- will safe check the sequence and prevent any undefined errors, -->
        <!-- even if the final value is undefined we use the || operator to default it to zero! -->                                
        <thead *ngIf="(invData?.columns?.[table]?.length || 0) > 0"></thead> 
    </table>
</div>

TypeScript Playground

Thank you for your answer. Above solution is working for me.
But I have another case:
interface col { name: string, id?: string| number }
In html:
`<tr *ngFor="let row of invData?.line_items?.[table];">
                  
               <span *ngIf="row?.[column?.id]?.value';>

`
Error: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ngtsc(2538)
It shows error for *ngIf="row?.[column.id]?.value"
column is of type col (interface). In which id can be undefined.

@HarwinderSingh Could you try *ngIf="(column?.id || column?.id === 0) && row?.[column.id]?.value"
